# How do I repeat a python script?

Tags: python

```
import random
my_list = ("123456789")

player = input("number? - ")
if player == random.choice(my_list): 
    print("you win")
else:
    print("you lose")
```

Now after "you win" or "you lose" is printed I want the script to run again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the `while` loop. It is goes in infinity because the `True` value there never changes. The important note is that the `input()` function must be below the `while` declaration.

```
import random
my_list = ("123456789")
while True:
    player = input("number? - ")
    if player == random.choice(my_list): 
        print("you win")
    else:
        print("you lose")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `while loop`:

```
import random
my_list = ("123456789")
while True:
    player = input("number? - ")
    if player == random.choice(my_list): 
        print("you win")
    else:
        print("you lose")
```

But remember that you need to `break` the loop for further code execution if some condition will be true, for example:

```
import random
my_list = ("123456789")
while True:
    player = input("number? - ")
    if player == random.choice(my_list): 
        print("you win")
        break # if player wins break the loop, if lose continue until win
    else:
        print("you lose")
```